# Can I nest itemprop if it read semantically?

Tags: microdata, schema.org

I'm working on a product page on a eComm solution and I'm using Schema.org for the first time. I have a product `name` and inside of that is the `brand` and `model`. Is this acceptable?

```
<h2 itemprop="name">
  <span itemprop="brand">Brand Name</span>
  <span itemprop="model">######</span>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see anywhere in the [Microdata spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/microdata.html#names%3a-the-itemprop-attribute) that explicitly allows this but it looks like [the Google parser](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=uploaded:8004e90a1354b1acd703eb80fc0387e7) accepts it.

Comment: Thanks! I think the Google Parser says it all!

Answer (score 0):

The [algorithm for finding the value of a property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#values) defines (in the last step, which applies in your example):

> The value is the element's `textContent`.

(i.e., the text content of the element and its child elements)

So according to this, the value of `name` should be "Brand Name ######".

The [algorithm for finding the properties of an item](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#associating-names-with-items) contains this step:

> If *current* does not have an `itemscope` attribute, then: add all the child elements of *current* to *pending*.

So the child elements of an element containing `itemprop` are checked for `itemprop` attributes, too.